# Disabling a constructor entirely using `std::enable_if`

Tags: c++, sfinae, enable-if

I have a template type which is parameterized with a certain pointer type. (like an iterator). I want this type to be implicitly castable to a version of itself with a const qualifier (e.g. `thing<const int*>(const thing<int*>&`). I want this constructor to be disabled when the pointer is already `const` as it clashes with the default copy constructor. Currently I have something similar to this snippet of code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Ptr>
struct traits {
    using ptr_type = Ptr;
    static constexpr bool is_const = std::is_const_v<std::remove_pointer_t<ptr_type>>;
    template <typename _Ptr> using rebind = traits<_Ptr>;
};

template <typename Traits>
struct thing {
    using ptr_type = typename Traits::ptr_type;
    using non_const_ptr_type = std::add_pointer_t<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_pointer_t<ptr_type>>>;
    using non_const_traits_type = typename Traits::template rebind<non_const_ptr_type>;

    thing(ptr_type p = nullptr) : ptr_(p) {}
    thing(const thing&) = default;

    template <typename = std::enable_if_t<Traits::is_const>>
    thing(const thing<non_const_traits_type>& other) :
        ptr_(const_cast<ptr_type>(other.ptr_)) {}

    ptr_type ptr_;

    template <typename> friend struct thing;
};

int main() {
    thing<traits<      int*>> t;
    thing<traits<const int*>> j(t);
}
```

The `thing` type gets its parameter from a traits type because this more accurately represents my real code. I tried to disable the constructor using `std::enable_if` but for some reason the compiler keeps complaining about the `enable_if` on a `non-const thing`.

```
error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
    using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
```

Putting the `enable_if` in the constructor's argument list does not help either. Compiled with GCC 8 with `-std=c++17`. [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/arGxk2) is a Godbolt link with the code.

Comment: It has to complain, there is no other constructor the compiler could use. You need to provide an additional constructor for when `Traits::is_const` is false.

Comment: What about `thing()`, `thing(ptr_type)` and `thing(const thing&)`? I don't want the fourth constructor to exist when `Traits::is_const` is `false`.

Comment: @Corristo The error message is from `thing<traits<int*>> t;`. It should choose `thing(ptr_type)`.

Comment: Because then `Ptr` is not `const` `thing(const thing&)` and `thing(const thing<non_const_traits_type>&)` have the same signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make `std::enable_if` dependent on template parameters of the constructor not the class:

```
template <class T = Traits, typename = std::enable_if_t<T::is_const>>
thing(const thing<non_const_traits_type>& other) :
    ptr_(const_cast<ptr_type>(other.ptr_)) {}
```